# Guava caching using independent keys

Tags: java, caching, guava

When working with user objects coming from a database one has usually an id and a username and it's common to search a user by id or by username.

If I now want to find users and like to use Guava caches I have to create two caches. One is caching by id, one is caching by username.
But both point to the same object.

Is it possible to use one LoadingCache only?

I thought about using the User Object itself as key `LoadingCache<User, User>` and implement equals and hashcode in the User object.
In the equals Method it's easy to say two User objects are equal if either the id **or** the username is equal.
But how can I generate a good hashCode Method that works for this scenario?

Any ideas on that?

Comment: It's not clear to me _why_ you want to use only one cache.  Using two caches seems like the right thing to do in this scenario.  (And making your equals method work like that will definitely break things; `equals` is expected to be transitive and your logic is not.)

Comment: In Guava Cache's predecessor, I had an example of an [indexable cache](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/IndexableCache) that provided this capability. Its too rarely needed that we didn't introduce that concept into Guava. The basic idea could be adapted in your own code, though (e.g. using Guava's `Striped`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for the answers, especially from the Guava developer itself. The suggest Solution was way to much work for me, I'm lazy ;).

So if I never the less will have to caches, I decided to solve it this way.

```
final LoadingCache<Serializable, Optional<ITemplate>> templatesById = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(MAX_CACHE_SIZE).expireAfterAccess(MAX_CACHE_LIFE_TIME, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build(new CacheLoader<Serializable, Optional<ITemplate>>() {

            @Override
            public Optional<ITemplate> load(final Serializable id) {
                final ITemplate template = readInternal(id);
                final Optional<ITemplate> optional = Optional.ofNullable(template);
                if (template != null) {
                    templatesByKey.put(template.getKey(), optional);
                }
                return optional;
            }
        });

final LoadingCache<String, Optional<ITemplate>> templatesByKey = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(MAX_CACHE_SIZE).expireAfterAccess(MAX_CACHE_LIFE_TIME, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, Optional<ITemplate>>() {

            @Override
            public Optional<ITemplate> load(final String key) {
                final ITemplate template = byKeyInternal(key);
                final Optional<ITemplate> optional = Optional.ofNullable(template);
                if (template != null) {
                    templatesById.put(template.getId(), optional);
                }
                return optional;
            }
        });
```

It means, that I don't wast memory for having two instances of a template in two caches. So I just add a template to both caches, if it was received from the database.

It works really good and is damn fast.
The only question was, when to tell the cache to refresh.
In my scenario it's only needed on delete or update.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void update(final ITemplate template) {
    super.update(new DBTemplate(template));
    templatesById.invalidate(template.getId());
    templatesByKey.invalidate(template.getKey());
}
```

That's it.
Any comments on that?

Comment: That is exactly the solution concept "populating the sister caches from the loader", I described and discussed in my answer, together with the Cons. The main problem is consistency, because there is no protection against that the two references in the caches point to different objects for a specific point in time. If you design you transaction boundaries correctly and byKeyInternal and readInternal have the transaction context two, you might work around that.

Comment: Why should they point to different Objects? They are only filled with the code you see. So this codes adds one Object to both caches. How come the difference?

Comment: I said for a specific point in time. It is a race condition. The put to the sister cache is finished before the load is finished.

Comment: If you only update through your update method and the Transaction annotation mans, that the database commit is done after the invalidation, then it works. As long as every update goes to this code and as long as everybody understands the implications after years....

Answer (score 1):

> When working with user objects coming from a database one has usually an id and a username and it's common to search a user by id or by username.

Remark: "search" means something different to me, then accessing. Maybe the id and the username have different usage patterns? Maybe the username is only needed at login time?

Avoid using two different concepts for referencing / accessing a user in your application. Decide for one use it consistently. Is the username unique? Can it change?

Two caches: You can use two caches and populate the "sister cache" from the loader with `name2user.put(user.getName(), user)` or `id2user.put(user.getId(), user)`. This way the identical user object is in both caches. Still, I don't like it, because of cleanlyness and consistency issues.

The third issue is data duplication, if you decide to change to another solution. A cache may store the value not by reference but copy it into compact byte arrays and store it off-heap (EHCache3, Hazelcast, etc.). (Clean) code should not rely on the fact, that the cache stores its data by reference in-heap, if there is no real need for it.

As assumed above the two access paths will not be equal in usage. My recommendation:

- One cache to cache the user data with: `id -> User`
- Second cache for resolving the id only: `name -> id`

Don't mind the additional cache access in the case of `name`. Of course the loader of the second cache my already request a User for its purpose so you might want to prepopulate the first cache with it.